# AWS Athena query JSON array with AND Condition

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, unnest

I have JSON data like this saved in S3. I am using **ATHENA** to write select statements.

```
  {
   "sample_data":{
      "people":[
         {
            "firstName":"Emily",
            "address":{
               "streetAddress":"101",
               "city":"abc",
               "state":"",
               "phoneNumbers":[
                  {
                     "type":"home",
                     "number":"3"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"city",
                     "number":"4"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
          {
            "firstName":"Smily",
            "address":{
               "streetAddress":"102",
               "city":"def",
               "state":"",
               "phoneNumbers":[
                  {
                     "type":"home",
                     "number":"1"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"city",
                     "number":"1"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How Can I write a select statement that selects **streetaddress** and **city** where **home>2** and **city=4**;

I tried UNNEST but that did not help.

Expected Output:

```
streetAddress  city
101            abc
```

Tried this UNNEST but it extracted phoneNumbers to multiple rows.  So can not
query by both **home** and **city** as they are in **different** rows now.

```
SELECT  idx,JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x.n, '$.address.streetaddress') as streetaddress,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x.n, '$.address.city') as city, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x.m, '$.type') as type, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x.m, '$.number')  as value
  FROM sample_data1 cross join
  UNNEST (CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(sample_data,'$.people') AS ARRAY<JSON>)) AS x(n)
  CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST (CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(x.n,'$.address.phonenumbers') AS ARRAY<JSON>))  WITH ordinality AS x(m,idx) ;
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Updated question, Can you please help me with that?

Comment: And what was your failed `UNNEST` statement? Can you please add it and explain why it didn't help?

Comment: Why are your integer values quoted? That makes them strings and not protected from being set to invalid numeric values.

Comment: Your question states you just want the street and city, but your query also selects phone type and number. What, precisely, do you need to select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unnest` flattens data into multiple rows, so you can process the array without unnesting using array functions. Version of Presto currently used by Athena does not support `any_match` so you will need to use `cardinality` + `filter` combination (and it does not support filtering via json path):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (json_str) AS (
    VALUES (
            json '{
            "firstName":"Emily",
            "address":{
               "streetAddress":"101",
               "city":"abc",
               "state":"",
               "phoneNumbers":[
                  {
                     "type":"home",
                     "number":"11"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"city",
                     "number":"4"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }'
        ),
        (
            json '{
            "firstName":"Smily",
            "address":{
               "streetAddress":"102",
               "city":"def",
               "state":"",
               "phoneNumbers":[
                  {
                     "type":"home",
                     "number":"1"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"city",
                     "number":"1"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }'
        )
) -- query
select street_address,
    city
from (
        select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_str, '$.address.streetAddress') as street_address,
            JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_str, '$.address.city') as city,
            cast(
                JSON_EXTRACT(json_str, '$.address.phoneNumbers') as array(json)
            ) phones
        from dataset
    )
where cardinality(
        filter(
            phones,
            js->json_extract_scalar(js, '$.type') = 'home'
                and try_cast(json_extract_scalar(js, '$.number') as integer) > 2
        )
    ) > 0 -- check for home
    and
    cardinality(
        filter(
            phones,
            js->json_extract_scalar(js, '$.type') = 'city'
                and json_extract_scalar(js, '$.number') = '4'
        )
    ) > 0 -- check for city
```

Output:

| street_address | city |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | abc |

Comment: `UNNEST` ***can*** be combined with aggregation and a `HAVING` clause to achieve the same effect, but I do prefer this approach.

Comment: But prepared statements is not working here
 filter(
            phones,
            js->json_extract_scalar(js, '$.type') = 'home'
                and try_cast(json_extract_scalar(js, '$.number') as integer) > ?
        )
It says "Incorrect number of parameters: expected 0 but found 1"